# iOS pathForResource show file name only

Tags: iphone, ios

I am implementing an audio player in my app. and I have a UITableView in which i show my list of audio tracks.

the list of audio is added into an array with

```
fileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"A Million Years" ofType:@"mp3"],
                 [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2 Million Years" ofType:@"mp3"],...
```

and in my cellForRowAtIndexPath I am doing

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.fileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

but the problem is that it still shows me an entire extension "/Users/....". i only want the file name ("A Million Years", "2 Million Years") to be shown.

What am I doing wrong? I have been looking around for an answer but was never able to get it (perhaps due to wrong phrasing)

Thanks very much everybody. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `lastPathComponent` if you want the last part of it. So:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.fileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

Comment: wow that was easy. could i also remove the extension at the same time too?

Comment: thank you so so much. i am really new to Obj-C so it didnt occur to me so much to stack all those calls together. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is not the extension. It's called the 'path'. (It would be good to at least get yourself to an acceptable level of knowledge in *using* a computing device before trying to program it...)

I suggest you use

```
[somePath lastPathComponent]
```

instead in order to get the filename only without the containing directories.

Also, the call to `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` is completely superfluous, wastes memory and processor time (which is unacceptable, especially on an embedded device).

Comment: oh yes the path, moment of folly that i typed the wrong thing. but i wanted the extension removed too. thanks for the enlightenment nevertheless. :)